# Weird output of pg_stat_activity

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have troubles with the output of this simple query:

```
select 
   pid, 
   state 
from pg_stat_activity 
where datname = 'My_DB_name'
```

while running it different ways:

1. In IDE
2. Via running psql in terminal
3. In bash script:

`QUERY="copy (select pid, state from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'My_DB_name') to stdout with csv"`

```
psql -h host -U user -d database -t -c "$QUERY" >> result
```

1 and 2 return results as I need them:

1:

```
 pid     state                         
 ------  ----------------------------- 
 23126   idle                          
 25573   active                        
 2642    active                        
 20420   idle                          
 23391   idle                          
 5339    idle                          
 7710    idle                          
 1558    idle                          
 12506   idle                          
 2862    active                        
 716     active                        
 9834    idle in transaction (aborted)
```

2:

```
  pid  |             state             
-------+-------------------------------
 23126 | idle
 25573 | idle
  2642 | active
 20420 | idle
 23391 | idle
  5339 | active
  7710 | idle
  1558 | idle
 12506 | idle
  2211 | active
   716 | active
  9834 | idle in transaction (aborted)
```

3 is weird - it doesnt give me any state name except 'active'

```
23126,
25573,
2642,
20420,
23391,
5339,
7710,
1558,
12506,
1660,active
716,active
1927,active
9834,
```

What am I missing? How to get all the state names via bash script?

Comment: Are you connecting as the same user in all cases? `pg_stat_activity` will show different output to a superuser than to a normal user.

Comment: Yep, the reason was in connecting as  not-superuser. Thank you.

Comment: @jmelesky, could you post your comment as an answer? So I can select it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_stat_activity` is a catalog view that will show different content depending on whether you're logged in as a superuser, or as a non-privileged user.

From your output, it looks like you're logged in as superuser in #1 and #2, but as a normal user in #3.